# Spotify API not returning user data, response code 200

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spotify

I'm getting my server-end set up and to connect with Spotify. Currently the OAuth flow is working correctly, I am successfully redirected to the Spotify log in page, Callback returns to my app with access_token, token_type, expires_in, refresh_token, and scope. I have the /refresh_token redirect working as well. When I try to console.log() my user data I get nothing, even though the response.status === 200.

Any ideas as to why I'm not receiving my user information?

````
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  const state = generateRandomString(16);
  const scope = "user-read-private user-read-email";

  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  const usp = new URLSearchParams({
    response_type: "code",
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: scope,
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    state: state,
  });
  const uspString = usp.toString();
  console.log(usp);

  res.redirect(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${uspString}`);
});

app.get("/callback", (req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code || null;
  const state = req.query.state || null;

  const usp = new URLSearchParams({
    code: code,
    state: state,
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
  }).toString();

  console.log("Here is the callback");
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    data: usp,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: `Basic ${new Buffer.from(
        `${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`
      ).toString("base64")}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.status);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const { access_token, token_type } = respone.data;
        axios
          .get("https://api.spotify.com/v1", {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `${token_type} ${access_token}`,
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            res.send(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2)}</pre>`);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            res.send(error);
          });
      } else {
        res.send(response);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.send(error);
    });
});

app.get("/refresh_token", (req, res) => {
  const { refresh_token } = req.query;
  const usp = new URLSearchParams({
    grant_type: "refresh_token",
    refresh_token: refresh_token,
  }).toString();

  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    data: usp,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: `Basic ${new Buffer.from(
        `${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`
      ).toString("base64")}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      res.send(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.send(error);
    });
});```
````

Comment: I think you are missing the `/me` at line 49 in your request: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-current-user/

Answer (score 0):

Misspelled response.data in the callback function.

originally respone.data => response.data